# AWK Script Incorrect Output - Duplicates in Column

Tags: awk

I am trying to extract the description of multiple script files and include the filename of the script in the description. My problem is the command produces multiple duplicates of the filename in the first column. Could you please advise how to remove the duplicates?

Also I would have copied this code from stackoverflow and modified it, but I don't 100% understand it. I would be grateful if you can explain what `gsub` does and what is the function of `$0`, `e=1` and `e==1`.

#### My code

```
awk '/\]\]/{e=0}/description\ =\ \[\[/{gsub("^.*description ","",$0);e=1}{if(e==1){print FILENAME, $0}}' file
```

#### Input

```
local stdnse    = require "stdnse"
local shortport = require "shortport"
local tn3270    = require "tn3270"
local brute     = require "brute"
local creds     = require "creds"
local unpwdb    = require "unpwdb"
local nmap = require "nmap"
local string = require "string"

description = [[
TSO User ID enumerator for IBM mainframes (z/OS). The TSO logon panel
tells you when a user ID is valid or invalid with the message:
 <code>IKJ56420I Userid <user ID> not authorized to use TSO</code>.

The TSO logon process can work in two ways:
1) You get prompted with <code>IKJ56700A ENTER USERID -</code>
   to which you reply with the user you want to use.
   If the user ID is valid it will give you a normal
   TSO logon screen. Otherwise it will give you the
   screen logon error above.
2) You're given the TSO logon panel and enter your user ID
   at the <code>Userid    ===></code> prompt. If you give
   it an invalid user ID you receive the error message above.

This script relies on the NSE TN3270 library which emulates a
TN3270 screen for NMAP.

TSO user IDs have the following rules:
 - it cannot begin with a number
 - only contains alpha-numeric characters and @, #, $.
 - it cannot be longer than 7 chars
]]

---
-- @args tso-enum.commands Commands in a semi-colon seperated list needed
-- to access TSO. Defaults to <code>tso</code>.
--
-- @usage
-- nmap --script=tso-enum -p 23 <targets>
--
-- @usage
-- nmap -sV -p 9923 10.32.70.10 --script tso-enum --script-args userdb=tso_users.txt,tso-enum.commands="logon applid(tso)"
```

#### Actual output

```
tso-enum.nse = [[
tso-enum.nse TSO User ID enumerator for IBM mainframes (z/OS). The TSO logon panel
tso-enum.nse tells you when a user ID is valid or invalid with the message:
tso-enum.nse  <code>IKJ56420I Userid <user ID> not authorized to use TSO</code>.
tso-enum.nse 
tso-enum.nse The TSO logon process can work in two ways:
tso-enum.nse 1) You get prompted with <code>IKJ56700A ENTER USERID -</code>
tso-enum.nse    to which you reply with the user you want to use.
tso-enum.nse    If the user ID is valid it will give you a normal
tso-enum.nse    TSO logon screen. Otherwise it will give you the
tso-enum.nse    screen logon error above.
tso-enum.nse 2) You're given the TSO logon panel and enter your user ID
tso-enum.nse    at the <code>Userid    ===></code> prompt. If you give
tso-enum.nse    it an invalid user ID you receive the error message above.
tso-enum.nse 
tso-enum.nse This script relies on the NSE TN3270 library which emulates a
tso-enum.nse TN3270 screen for NMAP.
tso-enum.nse 
tso-enum.nse TSO user IDs have the following rules:
tso-enum.nse  - it cannot begin with a number
tso-enum.nse  - only contains alpha-numeric characters and @, #, $.
tso-enum.nse  - it cannot be longer than 7 chars
```

#### Desired output

```
tso-enum.nse  
 description = [[
    TSO User ID enumerator for IBM mainframes (z/OS). The TSO logon panel
    tells you when a user ID is valid or invalid with the message:
     <code>IKJ56420I Userid <user ID> not authorized to use TSO</code>.

    The TSO logon process can work in two ways:
    1) You get prompted with <code>IKJ56700A ENTER USERID -</code>
       to which you reply with the user you want to use.
       If the user ID is valid it will give you a normal
       TSO logon screen. Otherwise it will give you the
       screen logon error above.
    2) You're given the TSO logon panel and enter your user ID
       at the <code>Userid    ===></code> prompt. If you give
       it an invalid user ID you receive the error message above.

    This script relies on the NSE TN3270 library which emulates a
    TN3270 screen for NMAP.

    TSO user IDs have the following rules:
     - it cannot begin with a number
     - only contains alpha-numeric characters and @, #, $.
     - it cannot be longer than 7 chars
    ]]
```

Comment: I suggest renaming the question to something like, "AWK script incorrect output."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Understanding

With these blocks, the author is defining a range by toggling a flag, `e`, when in / out of said range:

```
# end of range
/\]\]/ {
    e = 0
}

# start of range
/description = \[\[/ {
    gsub("^.*description ", "", $0)
    e = 1
}
```

String function `gsub` substitutes *any* occurrence of the first argument with the second argument found in the third argument. In this case, regex `"^.*description "` is matching the beginning of `$0`, the current *record* (in this case a record is a *line*), up to the string `description`, and replacing that with an empty string thus removing it, leaving the line with the actual description.

The last block below, just prints the line and `FILENAME` if it's in the description range:

```
{
    if (e == 1) {
        print FILENAME, $0
    }
}
```

---

## Modification

The modifications required is to print the `FILENAME` at the *start* of the range, indent lines within the range, and reorder the blocks:

```
# end range
/\]\]/ {
    e = 0
}

# in range
e == 1 {
    printf "\t%s\n", $0
}

# start range
/description = \[\[/ {
    print FILENAME
    e = 1
}
```

I removed the useless (at least for sample data) `gsub()` call.

**Invocation:**

```
$ awk -f script.awk data.txt
```

**Output:**

```
data.txt
        TSO User ID enumerator for IBM mainframes (z/OS). The TSO logon panel
        tells you when a user ID is valid or invalid with the message:
         <code>IKJ56420I Userid <user ID> not authorized to use TSO</code>.

        The TSO logon process can work in two ways:
        1) You get prompted with <code>IKJ56700A ENTER USERID -</code>
           to which you reply with the user you want to use.
           If the user ID is valid it will give you a normal
           TSO logon screen. Otherwise it will give you the
           screen logon error above.
        2) You're given the TSO logon panel and enter your user ID
           at the <code>Userid    ===></code> prompt. If you give
           it an invalid user ID you receive the error message above.

        This script relies on the NSE TN3270 library which emulates a
        TN3270 screen for NMAP.

        TSO user IDs have the following rules:
         - it cannot begin with a number
         - only contains alpha-numeric characters and @, #, $.
         - it cannot be longer than 7 chars
```

Comment: Hello Rafael, many thanks for the explanation and the answer, much appreciated, it works

Comment: @NarendraRajcoomar Your welcome, sir. Marking as Accepted Answer and Up-Vote is appreciated :). Also, welcome to SO!

Comment: unfortunately im @ level 13 and I cant vote up as yet, but I will, Ive marked it as the answer, many thanks once more